# iOS simulator not responding

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

Using both Xcode 4.4 and 4.5, I can't get the iOS simulator to actually start. It used to work, but one day it just stopped without any reason. I've tried reinstalling Xcode many times and rebooting, but to no avail. It just sits there bouncing away in the Dock, almost taunting me. Running my app on an actual iPad works fine, though. What could be causing this?

[Here's the output I get from force closing it.](http://sebsauvage.net/paste/?b59d1a22e3e63ffc#uIgkbae7P4w7KlFxMH5lcHJqbbVS8S/whloec/6u4no=)

EDIT: it works now. The only thing I did was delete com.apple.finder.plist in ~/Library/Preferences to fix my Time Machine not working. Whether or not it was actually this that did it, I don't know, but it works now.

Comment: Actually, it was posting your problem here that made it work.  Happens quite frequently.

Comment: I've always suspected that, but now my hunch has been confirmed.

Comment: yes, and calling yourself notverycreative actually makes you not very creative, change it to supercreative and you can suddenly move mountains :)

Comment: for me after shut down and starting mac solve the stuck problem, not restarting